# Does await PutObjectAsync(PutObjectAsync, CancellationToken) really awaits until the uploading finish in AWS SDK for .NET?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-sdk-net

I'm using the `AmazonS3Client.PutObjectAsync(PutObjectAsync, CancellationToken)` method to upload my files to s3 storage.
so the code inside my service looks like

```
await _client.PutObjectAsync(putObject, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I have to wait until the upload completes because the next service should download these files.

Now, I'm facing the problem - `PutObjectAsync` is executed, but s3 doesn't contain the file I need, it appears only after a few seconds after my program is finished.

I checked the `PutObjectResponse` class but didn't find anything which can explain if a file was completely uploaded. I also didn't find info about `PutObjectAsync` method behavior.

So the question is if `PutObjectAsync` combined with `ConfigurateAwait(false)` really waits for upload completion or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: `ConfigurateAwait(false)` is **only** concerned with the synchronization-context around the `await` (usually selecting the thread that will execute the continuation) - it is unrelated to how S3 processes your uploads or how the client proceeds after the `PUT` request is completed - so no, it isn't anything to do with your usage of `ConfigureAwait`. If you do observe that it has an effect then there's something terrible going-on inside Amazon's S3 client library and you should file a bug.

Comment: Thank you, just read about the ConfigurateAwait more and it's clear to me that the problem is not in async method usage.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `await PutObjectAsync` will (asynchronously) wait until the upload is complete.

> Now, I'm facing the problem - PutObjectAsync is executed, but s3 doesn't contain the file I need, it appears only after a few seconds after my program is finished.

What you're seeing is eventual consistency, which is almost ubiquitous with cloud services. The file has been uploaded, but it may take some time to be available. The most basic approach to resolving this is to poll until the file "appears". I'm not familiar with the details of S3, but some cloud services offer a "read my own writes" or some kind of flag that causes the `Put` to be delayed until the file can be read; that simplifies your code but in reality is just moving the polling to Amazon's servers.

Comment: Thank you for guidance, I'll check SDK documentation for it.